# Intellij plugin testing with Jubula

Tags: intellij-idea, jubula

I need automate the testing of an Intellij plugin using Jubula. Some functionalities change the color of the texts in the source code editing area. Need to check whether the selected text's color is changed or not by using jubula tests. When the source code editing area is mapped using mapping mode it shows the properties of the text area but always shows the "selectedTextColor" property as null. Can someone give a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure Jubula could properly map the source code editor?

Jubula is not so good at mapping complex components, your editor sounds too tricky for it. That's why you get null, probably.

I would try to position the mouse to the highlighted text, and then read properties under the cursor. See my answer here about how you could do it:

[Jubula RCP Applicaiton - Check Background Color of TableViewer Cell when Row is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846463/jubula-rcp-applicaiton-check-background-color-of-tableviewer-cell-when-row-is/36847351#36847351)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try that